# Unable to fetch date from datepicker using ng-model and ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am simply trying to create one small web-app in which user can download the values from database within certain time range. My `html` code goes like this:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class='col-md-5'>
                Start Date:
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                        <input type='text' ng-model="queryDate.start" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-5'>
                End Date:
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                        <input type='text' ng-model="queryDate.end" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class='col-md-5'>
                Service Name:
             <select id="serviceName" style="font-size: 15px;padding: 5px;width: 300px" >
                 <option></option>
                 <option ng-repeat="webService in webServices">{{ webService.fields.service }}</option>
             </select>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <button type="button" id="download" ng-click="download(queryDate)" class="btn btn-theme" style="float: right">Download</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to collect the start date and end date into ng-model

`ng-model="queryDate.start"`

`ng-model="queryDate.end"`

Although its quiet easy to collect data from ng-model as we can see in http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

My `mainApp.js` is as below

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
mainApp.controller("serviceController",function($scope,$http){
$http.get("/fetchData/").success(function(response){
    $scope.webServices = response;
});
//--------- I get alert "Hola" but the next alert says "undefined" ---------
$scope.download = function(queryDate){
    alert('Hola');
    alert(queryDate);
  };
});
```

I expect to collect both date field and later use them in DB to fetch the data.

Comment: Use should be using jquery-ui library and then provide a id to your input field then do this in js file  $('#yourid').datepicker();

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='input-group date' >
                        <input type='text' ng-model="queryDate.start" id='datetimepicker6'class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
```

In you JS file do this
$('#datetimepicker6').datepicker();

You have to user jquery-ui library for datepicker()

for example see this https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Mmmm..... I want to do it in angular way. What u r suggesting is jquery way. Isn't it?

Comment: yeah, So you can look at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker   ... This is angular way